# vpc configuration is not supported for WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to build a new project codebuild with terraform, I wanna configure a aws_codebuild_project like a Linux configuration but I'm retrieving the below error:

```
 Error: creating CodeBuild project: InvalidInputException: Invalid vpc config: vpc configuration is not supported for WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER projects
```

When I created a new resource with linux configuration I don't have any problem, this is my current configuration:

```
 "codebuild_configuration": {
        "cb_compute_type": "BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM",
        "cb_image": "aws/codebuild/windows-base:2019-1.0",
        "cb_type": "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER"
    }
```

I wanna get some ideas about that.

Could you support me to solve this issue?